# Use an angular 13 component in an angular 11 application

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

I've created an angular 13 lib (published on internal organization's npm) and an angular 11 application need it.

They cannot build their app with the lib, because of mismatch of typescript versions and other functionalities only supported since angular 12 (context in httprequests).

I downgrade my lib to be compiled in angular 11, build is ok, but their unit tests failed (reason of fails is not clear at all).

Now i think about turning my lib to a micro-frontend and exposes it.

Questions: can an angular 11 load an angular 13 micro-frontends?
Do i have other solution?

Comment: I don't see how anyone can answer this given how little information you have provided